# I'm getting an error importerror /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 version glibc_2.29' not found what should I do?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

While I run my python code in raspberry pi 3b+  I'm getting:

> importerror /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 version glibc_2.29' not
> found

error what should I do?

```
#beginner

pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Mirror-Interface-Auth/RaspberryPi-Module $ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/firestore.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore # pylint: disable=import-error,no-name-in-module
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1._helpers import GeoPoint
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_
```

Answer (score 3):

From this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/vjbL3IdZ2Vk/m/EcKSeD4eAgAJ), it seems an older version must be installed to work.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall grpcio 
sudo pip3 uninstall grpcio-status
```

Then

```
sudo pip3 install grpcio==1.44.0
sudo pip3 install grpcio-tools==1.44.0
```

After doing this my Raspberry Pi Zero W 2 does not fail upon importing the packages.

Comment: Still failing...